# Store sum query's result into JTable

Tags: java, jtable

I am new to Java. I want to query `Sale` table for duplicate `qty` and sum it up using a SQL `group by` query and store the results in JTable.

The following is my code which is not working. How can I fix this code?

```
try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver " +
        "(*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\SNDatabase1\\dist\\lib\\db11.accdb";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    Statement stt = con.createStatement();
    String q = "SELECT ID,SUM(Qty)FROM Sale GROUP BY ID";
    ResultSet rss = stt.executeQuery(q);

    while(rss.next()) {
        jTable7.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rss));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: For each row in the `ResultSet`, you are making a new `TableModel` from the `ResultSet` ... kind of a lot of waste.  Maybe you'd like to explain what isn't working so we don't waste each others time chasing tails

Comment: Don't think you need a loop here.

Comment: The `JdbcOdbcDriver` has been removed from Java 8+, for Access you can try [jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/). If you have a different error, please post it.